# getText() returning empty string in outside class using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, getter

I'm attempting to create a simple text editor in JavaFX but have stumbled upon a problem. My code that is supposed to save the current text can't get that text from the `TextArea` in my `Scene`. When I call `getText()` on the `TextArea` I just get back an empty string, even though something is written in there.

The `TextArea` is created in my `Main` class and assigned to a `static` field of a small helper-class called `Global`, so that it can be accessed in my other class `ApplicationMenu` where I call `getText()`.

Check out my source code at https://github.com/axelkennedal/Kode

Notes:

- `getText()`works as expected from inside my `Main` class
- I tested using a `TextArea` directly without encapsulating it in `TextEditor` and this works as expected when calling `getText()` on it from `ApplicationMenu`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, fixed it now :) @Jongware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by changing my implementation of TextEditor to this:

```
public class TextEditor extends TextArea
{

    TextEditor()
    {
        super();
    }

    public void printText()
    {
        System.out.println(getText());
    }
}
```